# how to parsee RSS feed avoiding html tags

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, rss

I am parsing the RSS feeds for my iphone app from popular news websites , 
i am using simple parser so , html tags are included in parsing data , but issue is that i want to show all information in my own way ,so can I extract text from these RSS Feeds.

Comment: Use XML Parsing to remove tags.Go through NSXMLParser in apple documentation

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627374/does-objective-c-have-a-strip-tags-function

Answer (score 0):

In this helpful tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2636/how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app-tutorial

used some files from MWFeedParser to determinate feed date (get NSDate from feed - very helpful).

But there is even more! NSString+HTML.h (.m) class extension do exactly you want (and event more - check it!)

You can get source code here:
https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser