# Objective C : Strip HTML except br tags

Tags: html, objective-c, ios7

I Want to strip the HTML to plain text except "br" tags. I need to replace the "br" tag with \n. so that new line is maintained in the converted plain text. How could I achieve this in Objective C.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the [MWFeedParser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser).

Comment: Can you add some content?  Answers that are nothing but links are less helpful, as SO seeks to generate answers that last long enough that the link may die.

Answer (score 1):

At least for maintaining the br tags as new lines, you could do this:

```
NSString* orgString = <something with html in it>
NSString* myString = [orgString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<br/>" withString:@"\n"];
```

[Then use the method in this post to remove the rest of the html.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627374/does-objective-c-have-a-strip-tags-function)

Was this what you needed?

Comment: And I need to remove &nsbp; , tabs and many special characters like these from the HTML string.